# which of the following statements are true in the given vector space of real valued functions?

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a subspace of the vector space of all real-valued continuous functions on a given set.

Assume that constant functions are in $V$ and that if $f$ $\varepsilon V$, then $f^2$  $\varepsilon V$ and that $|f|$ $\varepsilon$ $V$.

Then pick out the true statements:

1) if $f,g$ $\varepsilon$ $V$, then $fg$ $\varepsilon$ $V$

2) if $f,g$ $\varepsilon$ $V$, then $max${$f,g$} $\varepsilon$ $V$

3) if $f$ $\varepsilon$ $V$ and $p$ is any polynomial in one variable, with real coefficients, then $p(f)$ $\varepsilon$ $V$

I have no idea but I know that in vector space multiplication not holds.

Comment: Why should we assume that constants, products, and absolute values are in $V$? This follows from the definition.

Comment: I think you mean the following: $V$ is a subspace of all real-valued continuous functions with the property that constants are in $V$ and $V$ is closed w.r.t squares and absolute values...Right?

Comment: @ it is given in statement

Comment: products are not given but product of $f$ with $f$

Comment: doesn't it make sense?

Comment: $\varepsilon$ means belongs to

Comment: i have done it..

Comment: now i got your point

Answer (score 2):

- 1) $fg = \frac{(f+g)^2-(f-g)^2}{4}$.
- 2) $\max \{f,g\}=\frac{f+g+|f-g|}{2}$.
- $3)$ is trivial with $1)$.

Comment: @ MooS great . thanks